# How to fix IE support for line break using CSS pseudo-element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am just making a website on JavaScript References. For each topic I have a line break before the header with this CSS code below:

```
h3:before{
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

I tested it in all modern browsers and of course, IE 11 doesn't work as expected. I debugged IE and noticed that its properties above was strike-through, which I assumed was overridden by something else, however further investigating, I noticed IE's value set CSS with `content: normal;` and `white-space:normal;` which is not what I wanted.

[image: CSS strike thru]

**NOTE: Please test this [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/mxdqhpye/) in IE 11 and you'll notice, no line breaks before the headers.**

I resorted to how I could obtain the content's value with css-pseudo-elements and this is what I have in js so far:

NOTE: I do feel like I shouldn't be doing all this just to make a CSS line break work in IE 11. Is there a better way to make the pseudo-element w/ content property be recognized by IE browser?

```
<!-- Override Fix IE Bug that sets content:normal; & white-space:normal; -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
    //var contentProperty = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('h3'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
    //var whiteSpace = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('h3'), ':before').getPropertyValue('white-space');
    var h3 = document.querySelector('h3'), // returns h3
    contentProp = getComputedStyle(h3, ':before').content.toLowerCase().trim(); // returns "\a " ; IE returns "\"\n\""
    console.log("content : ", contentProp);
    if(contentProp !== "\"\\a \"" || contentProp === "normal" || contentProp === "")
    {
        contentProp = "\"\\a\""; // force IE to put value "\a" instead of "\n"

    }
    console.log("content : ", contentProp); // test value again

    var sheet = (function() {
    // Create the <style> tag
    var style = document.createElement("style");

    // Add a media (and/or media query) here if you'd like!
    // style.setAttribute("media", "screen")
    // style.setAttribute("media", "only screen and (max-width : 1024px)")

    // WebKit hack :(
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

    // Add the <style> element to the page
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    return style.sheet;
    })();

    // ERROR: IndexSizeError
    sheet.insertRule("h3:before{content: '\a'; white-space: pre;}", 1);
    sheet.addRule("h3:before", "content: '\a'; white-space: pre;", 1);
</script>
```

Also when I retrieve the getComputedStyle() from `content` in IE, its value is `"\n"`, not `"\a"`, not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: `margin-top` of `h3` is for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 11 recognizes the `:before` pseudo-element, but it just does not render a pseudo-element that contains nothing but a line break. Whether this is correct is an interesting question, but to circumvent the issue in your case, put e.g. a no-break space (U+00A0) there before the line break. That is, replace `content: "\a"` by `content: "\a0\a"`.

On the other hand, it would be easier and more flexible to set a top margin on the `h3` element rather than use generated content to add an empty line.

I don’t know why IE dev tools show the settings as struck-through. This seems to be a bug/feature in those tools, since the strike-through appears even when the code is modified as suggested above, in which case the CSS has visible effect. The same applies to using, say, `content: "*"` for testing.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the `0` in between `\a` and why it doesn't show in the browser, even though IE rendered it as something being there?

Comment: The `\a0 part denotes the character U+00A0, no-break space, which has no visible glyph but counts as content (whereas normal space might not). In CSS, a backslash `\` starts a notation so that browsers parse then a maximal string of hexadecimal digits, up to four digits.